# Does Django use case sensitive filenames for FileField with MySQL backend?

Tags: django, django-models, case-sensitive

I'm using Django 3.1.3 and have a model with a FileField field. When I upload a file with same name, but different case, the logic I have is reporting that it is a duplicate. For example:

```
Files <QuerySet ['92/565/20191222_152213.jpg', '92/565/cs_731__DSC8110.jpg', '92/565/ADs-2.MP4']>, this 92/565/ADS-2.mp4
```

The logic is...

```
        other_pieces_in_room = Piece.objects.filter(room__id=self.room_id)
        other_files_in_room = other_pieces_in_room.values_list('file', flat=True)
        mylog.debug("Files {}, this {}".format(other_files_in_room, file.name))
        if file.name in other_files_in_room:
                raise forms.ValidationError("...")
```

Model (relevant fields) is:

```
class Piece(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=media_location)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Any thoughts as to what is going on?

Comment: This is likely because you use an operating system with a case-insensitive filesystem like Windows.

Comment: Running on Ubuntu system

Comment: I see the issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve with Django. For all my tables, the collation for all the text fields are `utf8_general_ci` and not `utf8_general_cs`, so the FileField (and others) turns out to be case insensitive in database.  Not sure how that was set, and how to correct. As mentioned, this is on a linux system and not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, the database was created with the default settings.  The FileField in Django is stored in the database as a `varchar` and when doing:

```
show full columns from gallery_piece;
```

I could see that the field is using collation utf8_general_ci (which is case-insensitive).

I altered the database and all the char/varchar table fields to use `utf8mb4` character set and `utf8mb4_bin` collation, using commands like:

```
ALTER TABLE gallery_exhibit MODIFY file varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

Once done, the filename (and other char type fields) are treating files as case sensitive. I did read that on file upload, the validation will be case-sensitive, so will pass, but then a database integrity error will be encountered, when saving an entry with only case differences using the default collation.

For production, when I create the database, I'll need to do:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
  CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```